# Set Image from drawable as marker in Google Map version 2

Tags: android, marker, android-maps-v2

I am using this part of code to add a marker in a `MapFragment` in Google Map Version 2.

```
MarkerOptions op = new MarkerOptions();
op.position(point)
    .title(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getCity_name())
    .snippet(Location_ArrayList.get(j).getVenue_name())
    .draggable(true);
m = map.addMarker(op); 
markers.add(m);
```

I want to use different images from my drawable.

Comment: Do `BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_position_tennis_ball)` and then op.icon(icon);

Comment: Mr.Babar thanx for Your Answer its good and worked for me...U post it as a answer and i will accept it... Thanx Again.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar can we pass image at title

Comment: @muhammad i have look but i unable to do that...but it can dun.....

Comment: @muhammad i want to pass title in image

Answer (score 144, accepted):

This is how you can set a `Drawable` as a `Marker`.

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_position_tennis_ball)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
         .icon(icon);

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

---

*`VectorDrawables` and `XML` based `Drawables` do **not** work with this.*

Comment: This is correct, although the use of the word "any" drawable is incorrect.  This only allows you to set BitmapDrawables.  You can't, for example, set a drawable from xml with this.

Comment: Well, you can - you just need to paint it into a `Canvas` first (`drawable.draw(canvas)`), then dump the `Canvas` to a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Well guys i really don't have any idea about this right now! so let the up votes decide who is correct :)

Comment: Would have been a good question if it was about drawable that has been modified on code-behind, but it's currently a "press on autocomplete" question.

Answer (score 92):

@Lukas Novak answer is not showing anything because you also have to set the bounds on `Drawable`. 

**This works for any drawable. Here is a fully working example:**

```
public void drawMarker() {
    Drawable circleDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle_shape);
    BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(41.906991, 12.453360))
            .title("My Marker")
            .icon(markerIcon)
    );
}

private BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIconFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

*circle_shape.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ff00ff"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: My first marker drawn bigger than the others, I use exactly the same code with you. What might be the reason ? It's independent from the image source I tried with others.

Comment: I don't know. Post some code: the drawable xml or the cose used to create the drawable if you create it programmatically.

Comment: @vovahost Can you post the code for the circle_shape.xml. For some reason circle.getIntrinsicHeight/width return 0 for me

Answer (score 10):

If you have `Drawable` created programatically (so you have no resource for it), you can use this:

```
Drawable d = ... // programatically create drawable
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
d.draw(canvas);
BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
```

Then you have `BitmapDescriptor`, which you can pass into `MarkerOptions`.

Comment: This creates empty images for me

Comment: Please refer to the example posted by @vovahost for a fully working example of this approach. This answer isn't quite complete.

Answer (score 5):

**If you  are using `vector drawable` use this extension:**

```
fun  Context.bitmapDescriptorFromVector(vectorResId:Int): BitmapDescriptor {
    val vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, vectorResId)
    vectorDrawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth, vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight)
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.intrinsicWidth, vectorDrawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    vectorDrawable.draw(Canvas(bitmap))
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

And set to the marker icon:

```
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
         .title("Current Location")
         .snippet("Thinking of finding some thing...")
         .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector("Your icon resource id"))// call extension here

mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Basically use bitmap insted of drawable. If you do have a drawable, convert it to bitmap.**
Here is a code example in kotlin.

```
private fun placeNewMarker(whereToPlaceYourMarker: LatLng){

    val pickupMarkerDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_marker_drawable,null)


    _pickupMarker =   mMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(whereToPlaceYourMarker)
            .draggable(true)
            .title("My Marker")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pickupMarkerDrawable.toBitmap(pickupMarkerDrawable.intrinsicWidth, pickupMarkerDrawable.intrinsicHeight, null))))



}
```

Comment: Upvote for showing how to set a Vector Drawable as the marker icon